# cadvisor machine_cpu_cores metrics comes every 5 minutes

Tags: docker, prometheus, promql, cadvisor, victoriametrics

I am using Victoriametrics, cadvisor and docker to find our per container cpu usage. I am running the following query against cadvisor metrics

```
(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name != ''}[1m])) BY (instance, name) * 100) / ignoring(name) (sum by (instance) (machine_cpu_cores))
```

This should divide cpu_usage by machine_cpu_cores, but the metric machine_cpu_cores is available every 5 minutes, inspite of having a shorter collection interval in my config

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: node_exporter
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9100"]

  - job_name: cadvisor
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8080"]
```

This leads to the following break in the graph

[image]

This metric should be available at at least a 1 minute resolution. Has anyone else faced these issues with cadvisor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using the `on (instance) group_left()` expression instead of the `ignoring` flag

`(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name != ''}[1m])) BY (instance, name) * 100) / on(instance) group_left() (sum by (instance) (machine_cpu_cores))`

Answer (score 3):

Could you please check what returns the following queries on the same time interval:

```
scrape_interval(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])
scrape_interval(machine_cpu_cores[5m])
```

Do you have any non-default flags configured for your VictoriaMetrics process?

Comment: Both had given the value `60` - I no longer have the data source so cannot revalidate it. But this is a good way to know if scrape_interval is playing a part. Will +1 your answer. Was able to tweak the query and run it though as per my update.